# Hurting your feewings

Tags: meaning

What does the word "feewing" mean?
I heard it in an animation, "Zootopia".
At first I thought it was feeling, but it turned out I was wrong and the word is "feewing".
Is it an English word?!
Is it slang? Or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't give the context, but I expect the [following](http://www.latinospost.com/articles/82161/20160102/watch-full-trailer-of-disneys-zootopia-out-release-date-cast-plot-everything-we-know-so-far.htm) does

> Rookie officer Hopps takes the case just to prove herself to her team.
>   She then enlists the help of fox Nick Wilde ( voiced by Jason
>   Bateman). At first, Wilde is just as negative and pessimistic as
>   everyone else in Zootopia. When Officer Hopps attempted to place him
>   under arrest, he says, "For what, hurting your **feewings**?"

"Feewings" is "mispronounced", imitation baby talk for "feelings."  It is intended to belittle the person addressed as being too sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

It's just the word "feelings" pronounced with an exaggerated lisp, in imitation of baby talk, or the way some people talk to young children.

The phrase "did I hurt your feewings?" is an mildly insulting expression of patronizing fake sympathy.  It's meant to imply the listener is soft or babyish.

Comment: Yep.  If someone says "Aw, did your feewings get hurt?" they're expressing a belief that you're overreacting to some perceived slight.